# Wobble problem with the PF L motor

Tags: motor, power-functions, repair, disassembly

So I got my hands on a used 42095 LEGO Technic set that I wanted for a long time. After disassembling it and testing PF for the first time, I have noticed that one of the motors is extremely wobbly, to be specific the orange part, and this becomes obvious when I insert a long axle. I didn't take a look inside because I was afraid that I might damage certain part in there. For the record, the motor works fine, but it is extremely loud compared to the other one, and it makes this "vroom-vroom" sound. I suspect it may be one of the smaller gears in the inside that is misaligned and causing the wobble.

Any help how to fix that would be appreciated.

Also thank you Alex for correcting typos and other mistakes i made.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixing a not working Power Functions L motor](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/11671/fixing-a-not-working-power-functions-l-motor)

Comment: Hi Jackob and welcome to Bricks.SE! Sound like you're looking for ways to open the motor and check its innards with the intention to fix them, does [this](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/11671/fixing-a-not-working-power-functions-l-motor) answer your question then?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix the problem, thanks to everyone who took the time to provide help/advice. I managed to open the motor but it is impossible to do that without damaging the clips that are holding it in place.

As for the cause of the problem itself: the lubricant that was used on the tiny white planetary gears inside wasn't distributed equally throughout the orange bearings in the carrier, which created this bump that caused the whole mechanism to shift upward whenever the motor started spinning. I removed all planetary gears and applied the excessive lubricant to all of them and reassembled the motor - which fixed the wobble, but it also fixed that nasty sound it was making.

Hopefully, this will help anyone who is suffering from the same problem, but beware: you will damage the clips. But it shouldn't be that bad.

Comment: You're welcome - but to be honest, no need to thank me for copyediting :)